# Open source speech recognition engine

Tags: php, open-source, audio, speech-recognition

I'm looking for a free (FOSS) speech recognition engine that I can use with my PHP-based GPL software. Any suggestions what are some of the best quality ones out there?

Comment: The answer is significantly different if you are looking for a limit vocabulary engine (for which there are choice) or a dictation type engine (for which there was nothing mature last time I looked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked [sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/)?